# namenode.LeaseExpiredException while df.write.parquet when reading from non-hdfs source

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a spark code that runs on a yarn cluster and converts csv to parquet using databricks library.

It works fine when the csv source is hdfs. But when the csv source is non-hdfs, which is usually the case, I come across this exception.
It should not happen as the same code works for hdfs csv source.

Complete link to the issue :
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19344

Comment: What is the source of the file? is it access-able from all nodes (e.g. is it url?). If the nodes can't access the file (e.g. if it is on a local-computer/node) - this error should be expected

Comment: yes it is accessible...the permission rights are hdfs:hdfs
and it is able to access the file as I give the directory name and it picks up the file name by itself....
The error is different if the files can't be located.

Comment: it is a local file though...i mean in the machine where I am running spark-submit...submit it as master --yarn..
so how to give input path for such files which are not distributed but are meant to be read for further distributed processing (if not via "file:///")

Comment: ok...i guess i was doing it wrong
the files need to be present on all hosts or in hdfs...this attempt at reading a local file is conceptually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments.

When the files are on the driver node, but not access-able by the nodes, the read will fail.

When using reading input file (e.g. `spark.read` in spark 2.0), the files should be be access by all executors nodes (e.g. when the files are on HDFS, [cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), etc)

Comment: @taransaini43 - If I've  answered your question, please accept/up-vote it